# Sort array by length of sub arrays

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, adjacency-list

So I have a 2D array `graph` that represents an adjacency list:

```
0:2 1 0
1:0 
2:
```

In array format thats:

```
[[2,1,0],[0],[]]
```

What I want to do is sort a **specific row** (say `graph[0]`) by the length of the sub array (the edge list).

In the example above the sorted `graph` would look like:

```
0:0 1 2
1:0 
2:

[[0,1,2],[0],[]]
```

Since `graph[0].length = 3` and `graph[1].length = 1` and `graph[2].length = 0`.

I've tried using:

```
Arrays.sort(graph[v], new DegreeComparator(graph));

class DegreeComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
  int[][] graph;

  public DegreeComparator(int[][] g) {
    graph = g;
  }

  public int compare(Integer c1, Integer c2) {
    return Integer.compare(graph[c1].length, graph[c2].length);
  }
}
```

But the sort method won't accept this format. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit for clarity:**

Because the above example uses numbers it's a bit confusing so I'll add a second case:

```
0: 4 1 2
1: 1 2 3
2: 
3: 4 1
4: 0

[[4,1,2],[1,2,3],[],[4,1],[0]]
```

Would become (if all rows were sorted):

```
0: 1 4 2 // Row 1 has more numbers than row for which has more than row 2
1: 1 3 2
2: 
3: 1 4
4: 0

[[1,4,2],[1,3,2],[],[1,4],[0]]
```

However, I only need to sort one row at a time! Not the whole thing.

Comment: The array you're sorting doesn't contain `Integer`s. It contains arrays. So you need a comparator that orders arrays, not `Integer`s.

Comment: Try to use a "natural" sort: `Arrays.sort(graph[v]);` (instead of `Arrays.sort(graph[v], new DegreeComparator(graph));`)

Comment: @khelwood: It contains an array of pointers. If I want to sort `graph[0]` that would be `sort([2,1])` Which contains integers.

Comment: @alfasin, natural sort orders the numbers numerically. The numbers are themselves pointers, and I need them ordered by the length of the array they correspond to.

Comment: In the example you gave you're sorting the inner-arrays from `[2,1]` to `[1,2]` - you're not sorting the arrays by length!

Comment: @Darkstarone: to sort an array of Bananas, you need a `Comparator<Banana>`. To sort an array of Persons, you need a `Comparator<Person>`. To sort an array of `int[]`, you need a `Comparator<int[]>`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: No, that's just a artifact of the example. I've changed it for clarity. The length of the array graph[1] is greater than the length graph[2] (1,2 being in the inner array im sorting). The numbers themselves are unimportant, since they are essentially pointers.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to sort a single row of ints at a time. Not the whole thing.

Comment: Then your title and description is wrong. You simply want to sort each array of ints. Use a for loop and, for each `int[]` sub array, call `Arrays.sort(subArray)`

Comment: @JBNizet That won't work. I do not want to sort the numbers numerically. The numbers are pointers to other arrays.

Comment: @Darkstarone How about you write a question that actually asks what you want instead of making us all guess?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand anything. Rewrite your question to explain what you mean by pointer, what every number represents, and give a concrete, unambiguous example of what you want. Your current example shows sub arrays sorted numerically.

Comment: Added a new example, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask your int[] to be sorted with a Comparator

Change the type of graph to Integer[][]

```
class DegreeComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    Integer[][] graph;

    public DegreeComparator(Integer[][] g) {
        graph = g;
    }

    public int compare(Integer c1, Integer c2) {
        return graph[c2].length - graph[c1].length;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's all I needed to do. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all just to clarify your question: you have an array of arrays called `graph`. You also have an array of ints (let's call it `pointers`) which refers to the elements of `graph`. The fact that `pointers` happens to be one of the elements of `graph` isn't actually important.

```
    Integer[][] graph = new Integer[4][];
    Integer[] pointers = new Integer[] { 2, 1, 0, 3 };
    graph[0] = pointers;
    graph[1] = new Integer[] { 0 };
    graph[2] = new Integer[] {};
    graph[3] = new Integer[] { 1, 2 };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pointers));
    // [2, 1, 0, 3]

    final int[] lengths = new int[graph.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
        lengths[i] = graph[i].length;
    }
    Arrays.sort(pointers, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return Integer.compare(lengths[o2], lengths[o1]);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pointers));
    // [0, 3, 1, 2]
```